# What is this movie where a woman is attacked and possessed by a worm

Tags: story-identification

**Warning: NSFW content**

Does anyone knows what is the name of this movie? Only just posted on YouTube recently.

Comment: It looks like a setup for a kinky movie.

Comment: [Shivers?](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073705/)

Comment: @JohnRennie I might have thought so but Shivers was released in the 1970s and apart from the cinematography looking far more recent (looks wide format digital where Shivers was narrower format film), the woman in the foreground is wearing an earbud, something that only came into existence several decades after Shivers would have been filmed.

Comment: This clip definitely calls to mind [David Cronenberg's Shivers (1975)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073705/) but the clip clearly comes from a more recent production. It appears that there was some buzz concerning a remake about 10 years ago, but I'm not finding evidence that such a project ever made it to completion/release. It would not surprise me if this is a Shivers remake, just not finding any confirmation.

Comment: @AnthonyX Ah, yes. I thought I recognised the parasite from Shivers, but I guess phallic parasites are pretty common in the lower reaches of the horror movie world :-)

Comment: *phallic parasites are pretty common in the lower reaches" snigger snigger

Comment: Looks like airpods - so movie is from 2016+, may be even from 2019+

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I have to say, really vile. I am sure it achieved its intention, as the mentioned Cronenberg manages -- I can just describe verbally what happens in, say, The Fly, and nauseate people. My question: I can understand be scared as fun in a movie -- sickened?? I think not. But I still like David Cronenberg's stuff for the most part.

Comment: @releseabe It depends what kind of "sickened" you mean. For example, Japanese horror artist Junji Ito is writing up stories which aren't kinky, unlike this. But you are guaranteed to feel uneasy when you read one, because it threads into psychological stuffs which some of us human-beings feel uncomfortable with. And I actually liked reading them, because that feeling is... well, peculiar. Otherwise, yeah, this isn't something I would watch personally. But to each their own, I guess.

Comment: @Clockwork: I am not being critical of authors/film makers; rather I genuinely wonder if being "grossed out" works for some people in the same way being frightened by fiction works for me and apparently many millions of others. I suspect people who like sickening stuff is a small proportion of the viewing audience. There is of course some big overlap twixt graphic violence and sickening things -- purely disgusting stuff like we see in the clip sure baffles me -- I am probably more sensitive than most. For example, I am unable to eat in public and I know that is weird.

Answer (score 12):

This is apparently episode 15 of the "Parasited" series, directed by Roberto Di Suna. This episode is called ["Parasited Therapy"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt26517161/?ref_=ttep_ep15)

> Sasha is in the middle of her therapy session with Josephine when she starts talking about her fear of tiny alien creatures that can control your mind. Josephine tries to reassure her, but as they speak, one of these creatures begins to creep into the room. To help calm Sasha, Josephine suggests listening to some relaxing music. As Sasha focuses on the music, the alien creature slips into the therapist, driving her into a sexual frenzy.

Comment: Nicely spotted. How do you find it?

Comment: OK, appears to be a correct identification - a very similar concept as "Shivers", but where the 1975 movie had an R rating, this is full-on XXX. Production values look pretty  Hollywood-slick for what appears to be basic porn with Eastern European performers.

Comment: @AnthonyX Actually, according to porn industry standards, that is just X, not even XX, much less XXX.  (The things you can learn from National Public Radio....)

Comment: @Buzz The posted scene is no more than X, sure, but I found other scenes from that show which are quite a bit more explicit. Try googling for the show title with performer full names and you'll see what I mean.